# Swift 4 shortcut syntax to add multiple objects, with some properities set, to an array?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

Is there some shorthand syntax which will allow me to add an object with it's properties set to an array. This is what I'm currently doing, however I'd like to append these objects all in one append statement.

I've tried various syntax, using `self()` but I've not had much luck.

```
var selectFields = [iCloudSchemaFieldValue]()

let tid = iCloudSchemaFieldValue()
tid.setField(LoggerStartup.eTblTypes.tid)
selectFields.append(tid)

let name = iCloudSchemaFieldValue()
name.setField(LoggerStartup.eTblTypes.name)
selectFields.append(name)
```

Here's my enum

```
public enum eTblTypes
{
    public static let tid              = 2010
    public static let name             = 2020
    //
}
```

Here's my Objective C framework class..

```
@interface iCloudSchemaFieldValue : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger enumVal;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger tableEnumVal;
@property (nonatomic) id value;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL sysGenDefault;
@property (nonatomic) eOperator whereOperator;
@property (nonatomic) eOperator whereCondition;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger padAmount;

-(id)setField: (NSInteger)ev;

-(id)setFieldVal: (NSInteger)ev
           value: (id)value;

-(id)setFieldWithPadding: (NSInteger)ev
                 padding: (NSInteger)padding;

-(id)setFieldSysGenVal: (NSInteger)ev;

-(id)setWhereVal: (NSInteger)ev
           table: (NSInteger)tableEv
        operator: (eOperator)op
           value: (id)value
       condition: (eOperator)condition;

@end
```

I really don't want to add an init method to this class and I have several helper methods where I'd like to use the same short hand syntax approach.

Comment: Can you show us the `setField` method(s)?

Comment: It's from my Objective C framework `-(id)setField: (NSInteger)ev;`

Comment: Does that mean you can't modify the `iCloudSchemeFieldValue` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is much better, but you could do something like:

```
let selectFields: [iCloudSchemaFieldValue] = [
    LoggerStartup.eTblTypes.tid,
    LoggerStartup.eTblTypes.name,
    ... // add other fields you want to set here
].map {
    let obj = iCloudSchemaFieldValue()
    obj.setField($0)
    return obj
}
```

I assumed that `LoggerStartup.eTblTypes.tid` and `LoggerStartup.eTblTypes.name`  are of the same type `Int`, and that `iCloudSchemaFieldValue` is a type.

Now you only need to add one more line, instead of 3, each time you want to set a new field.

It would be best if you could edit `iCloudSchemaFieldValue` to add an initialiser that takes an `Int`. And then you could do:

```
let selectFields = [
    LoggerStartup.eTblTypes.tid,
    LoggerStartup.eTblTypes.name,
    ... // add other fields you want to set here
].map(iCloudSchemaFieldValue.init)
```

Comment: @Jules `setValue` takes an `Int` argument right? What is the type of `LoggerStartup.eTblTypes.tid`?

Comment: @Jules Oh wait! You called `setValue`. You should have called `setField`!

Answer (score 1):

Add an initializer in the `iCloudSchemaFieldValue` struct or class which takes a `LoggerStartup.eTblTypes` type and set the appropriate property in the init method

```
init(field: LoggerStartup.eTblTypes)
```

Then you can write

```
var selectFields = [iCloudSchemaFieldValue]()

selectFields = [iCloudSchemaFieldValue(field: .tid), 
                iCloudSchemaFieldValue(field: .name)]
```

Comment: Sorry I've actually got several methods to do different things, so I want to use the same approach for these if possible.

Comment: Elaborate your issue in the question!

Answer (score 1):

For that purpose you can add method that updates object and returns itself.
Let's call it `updating`.

```
extension iCloudSchemaFieldValue {
    func updating(with closure: (iCloudSchemaFieldValue) -> Void) -> iCloudSchemaFieldValue {
        closure(self)
        return self
    }
}
```

So your code will look as follows:

```
let selectFields = [
    iCloudSchemaFieldValue().updating(with: { $0.setField(LoggerStartup.eTblTypes.tid) }),
    iCloudSchemaFieldValue().updating(with: { $0.setField(LoggerStartup.eTblTypes.name) })
]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to append these objects all in one append statement.

You can do it like so:

`selectFields = [tid, name]`

But since your datasource `selectFields` has already been initialized, this would be fine:

`selectFields.insert(contentsOf: [tid, name], at: 0)`